Noob Question About Phaser Object Not Moving
well, i have just started learning js and ts for game development and am following a video course on the same. I have successfully specified an object and added it to the gamescreen. The object is interactive and i can change its alpha by clicking on it. But after adding the necessary phaser physics modules and references, the object simply disappears from the screen.
I was expecting the game object to move in the directions specified in the update function. Here are my code, its not in its original shape as i Have done some trial and error. But the problem remains- whenever i try to add some physics related code, the gameobject simply disappears from the game screen.
Game.ts

<code>
import 'phaser'



import PreloadScene from './scenes/preloadScene'
import MainScene from './scenes/mainScene'

export const GameScreen = {
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  };
  

const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffe0",
    scale:{
        parent: 'phaser-game',
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        width: GameScreen.width,
        height: GameScreen.height
    },
    scene:[PreloadScene,MainScene],

    Physics:{
        default: 'arcade',  
        arcade:{
            debug:true,
            gravity:{y:200}
        }
       
    
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const game = new Phaser.Game(config)
    
})
<code>

Main Scene
<code>

import Rocket from "../objects/rocket"; 
export default class MainScene extends Phaser.Scene{

    rocket: Rocket
    constructor(){
        super({
            key: 'MainScene'
        })
    }
    create(){
       this.rocket= new Rocket(this, this.cameras.main.width/2, this.cameras.main.height/2)
       //this.rocket.body.velocity.x +=3;
    }

    /*update(time: number, delta:number): void{
        this.rocket.body.velocity.x +=3;
       // this.rocket.body.velocity.y (3);
    }*/

}
<code>


`export default class Rocket extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite{
Rocket
<code>
export default class Rocket extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite{

constructor(scene, x,y){
    super(scene, x, y, 'rocket')

    scene.add.existing(this)
    
    

    this.setInteractive().on('pointerdown',() =>  {
           this.alpha= 0.5})
        
    }
    
    
    
    
}


I would try the following:

Set gravity: { y: 0 } to stop the rocket from being dragged off the screen.
Hard-code the x and y values instead of using the camera size. Try 400,300.
In your Rocket class, after scene.add.existing(this) add:
scene.physics.add.existing(this);

If you view source (Edit button) on this Phaser labs example, it's basically doing what you're trying to do, so is a good point of reference: https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Cextending%20arcade%20sprite.js
